# When do I need to put div. with two CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just wanted to know when is neccessary for me to place a div.cssclass when using two css classes together in my stylesheet. I normally troubleshoot by using with and without it until it works which obviously is fine and quick enough but I would be good to know the best practice.

Example:

```
.cssclass1 .cssclass2 { }
```

VS

```
.cssclass1 div.cssclass2 { }
```

Is it when its not a direct sibling to it, i.e the next class nested in there?

Comment: You can vote and check an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

If both those elements are divs, then there is **no difference**, except that

```
.cssclass1 .cssclass2 {
```

is faster than

```
.cssclass1 div.cssclass2 {
```

If you'd have let's say:

```
<div class="cssclass1">
    <div class="cssclass2"></div>
    <a class="cssclass2"></a>
</div>
```

then `.cssclass1 .cssclass2 {` would select both `div` and `a`, while `.cssclass1 div.cssclass2 {` would select only the div.

Comment: *specificity* is the difference

Answer (score 1):

The difference is **Specificity** because if you have `.cssclass1 .cssclass2`, all elements with that classes are affected **BUT** if you use `.cssclass1 div.cssclass2`, the only affected is the `<div>` element with the `cssclass2` class.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonjie said, it's about specificity.  Here's an example...

```
div .cssclass2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.cssclass1 div {
  background-color: blue;
}

div div {
  background-color: orange;
}
<div class="cssclass1">
<div class="cssclass2">
hello
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, none of the styling declarations are an exact match for our html here.  So, what colour should the background be?  CSS has a way to resolve this ambiguity by identifying the css that is most specific to the html.  There are some good blog posts about understanding CSS specificity.